# Unable to resolve target 'android-9' from FacebookSDK

Tags: java, android, eclipse, facebook

While I am importing Facebook SDK to Android ADT Eclipse, I am getting the following errors:

Project 'FacebookSDK' is missing required source folder: 'gen'  FacebookSDK     Build path  Build Path Problem
The project cannot be built until build path errors are resolved    FacebookSDK     Unknown Java Problem
Unable to resolve target 'android-9'    FacebookSDK     Unknown Android Target Problem

I tried to install Android(API9) but this one has been obsolete. Please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

because you don't have API level 9 in your SDK. Download & install it through Android SDK Manager.
Also, don't forget to click obsolete :)

Comment: Thanks so much! It works to me! I am new to Android development.

Answer (score 8):

It is better to change project.properties configuration under FacebookSDK. Just change target=android-9 to target=android-19.